# Cliente - Servidor Sql Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2000

mi duda se presenta, en Sql Server 2000 y Vb6, lo que quiero hacer es acceder con mi aplicación al Pc-servidor desde la Pc-cliente para acceder a los datos de la base. ¿Como hago para realizar esa conexión? ¿Por dónde empiezo?, desde ya muchas gracias y perdón, que conozca poco por los datos que les dejo, saludos.

Comment: ¿SQL Server 2000? Aún corre? ¡wow!

Comment: @jachguate y Visual Basic 6? Esto es más arqueología que informática lol

Comment: @PabloClaus haha, desgraciadamente siguen existiendo casos, de hecho pregunté a alguien porque no han cambiado, la razón "porque así funciona y no tiene problemas" =/ . recomendaría migrar a .NET al menos...

Comment: @Elenasys es que algunos todavía usan XP o Windows 2000 con máquinas que no pueden aguantarse .net. Hay rumores que dicen que andan a leña y carbón.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta puede ser una manera de hacerlo, aunque hay otras (Tuve que desempolvar un poco el código).

Para conectarte con **SQL Server 2000 y VB 6** lo más común es usar un objeto `ADOdb`. La conexión se arma con una cadena de conexión que tendrías que modificar a tus necesidades.

Una vez establecida la conexión, podés consultar los datos con un objeto recordset.

```
    Dim MyConnObj As ADODB.Connection ' Objecto ADODB Connection
    Dim myRecSet As New ADODB.Recordset 'Objeto Recordset
    Dim sqlStr As String ' String variable para almacenar la consulta a la base

    Set MyConnObj = New ADODB.Connection

    MyConnObj.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=IPServidor;Initial Catalog=NombreBaseDeDatos;User Id=Usuario;Password=Password;"

    MyConnObj.Open

    Set myRecSet = New ADODB.Recordset

    sqlStr = "select * from Empleados"

    myRecSet.Open sqlStr, MyConnObj, adOpenKeyset
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, desde ya muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Pablo y con el nombre de usuarios como haría, tengo que hacer un usuario, por cada pc-Cliente no?.

Comment: jajaja, se que son lenguajes viejos, pero lo bien que andan, igual tengo pensado migrar a .net, pero quería algo libre como lazarus, me gusto esa plataforma,es lenguaje delphi, y seguiré con sql server express 2005. Así Que entre esos lenguajes estoy decidiendo.

Comment: Hombre, @Rober, mejor vete de una vez al SQL server 2016, por qué razón te quedarías con el 2005, es casi tan viejo como el 2000.

Comment: @Jachguate y no cambia mucho el lenguaje en el 2016?, yo para tener un avance progresivo, pero si dices que me entenderé de igual manera con el 2016, no me tiembla el pulso y migro, otra cosa, está la versión express del 2016?

Comment: Si hay express en el 2016. Algunas cosas variaron, depende de que tanto tires de funcionalidades especiales o cosas muy internas. En SQL/Tablas/Ïndices, diría que un 90% o más de lo que te funcionaba en el 2000 seguirá funcionando en el 2016, solo que mejor.

Comment: @jachguate lo asustaste hermano! Casi se autoconvencía de migrar! jeje.  asi que robert como te explicaron, lo mejor es migrar a tecnologías que por lo menos tengan mantenimiento por parte del proveedor.

Comment: @Pablo, jajajaja, no es mi intención asustar a nadie... diré que el 95% funcionará entonces.. jajaja :D

Comment: Con respecto al usuario, no se hace un login por usuario de la aplicación, porque por eso es lo que se paga la licencia. Generalmente tienes un usuario general de la base de datos (el que usas para conectarte desde el código), y en tu aplicación manejas los usuarios que quieras. ¿Me explico?

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer la conexión puedes implementarlo en un modulo algo como:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Conexion"
Option Explicit
Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset

Public Sub Conectar()
  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  cn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=.;Database=DBPrueba;Uid=sa;Pwd=666;"
End Sub

Public Sub Desconectar()
  On Error Resume Next
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  cn.Close
  Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Usando esta conexión

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Te puedes guiar de [SQL Serverver 2000 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2000/)

Puedes usarlo desde una Clase Cliente:

```
Public Function GetCliente() As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim strSQL As String
  Conectar
  strSQL = "SELECT idCliente AS Código, nombre AS Nombre FROM Clientes"
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
  Set GetCliente = rs
End Function
```

El código es de ejemplo debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades.